# Ratchet Websockets - Instillation problems

Tags: websocket, installation, ratchet

I have been reading alot and still struggling getting this ratchet to work.  I am struggling just to get the server side shell script up and running. The vendor dir has  been moved from its original installed location but it was moved in its entirety.  when I run  php composer.phar update or install and each time is says nothing to update or install.

here is my dir structure:

```
/var/www/bin/socket.php (server script)
        /src/CommApp/Comm.php
        /htmp/ (public site)
        /vendor/
        composer.json
        composer.phar
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "CommApp": "src"
    }
},
"require": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*"
}
```

}

When I try the top version of the server code, it works but I can't figure out how to bind to a different IP, instead of 127.0.0.1  I need to bind to 0.0.0.0.  So I found this newer version of the code at the bottom that allows me to bind to the ip i need.  The buttom code gives me an error of 
*PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Ratchet\CommApp' not found in /var/www/bin/socket.php on line 28*

**socket.php**

```
<?php
/**
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use CommApp\Comm;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Comm()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
 */

 // Ratchet/0.3
$app = new Ratchet\App('www.mysite.com',8080,'0.0.0.0');
$app->route('/CommApp',new Comm);
$app->run();
```

Here is the code for **Comm.php**

```
<?php

namespace CommApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Comm implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        //store the new connection
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "someone connected\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        //send the message to all the other clients except the one who sent.
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "someone has disconnected";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not how I fixed it but I reinstalled everything and it worked.  I think that it had to do with the initial location of the installation of Ratchet, but I can't be sure.